# Compilation error on Eclipse Indigo : javax.servlet.jsp.JspException, javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jstl

I am getting following errors while adding following EL in a jsp in eclipse indigo.

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user">
...
</form>
```

However the application runs fine without any compilation error. I double check the servlet-api 2.5 and jst 1.2 jars are in class path in Eclipse IDE.

If I remove `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` it doesn't show any errors.

Can anyone one help me to get me out of this errors?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysterious Eclipse JSP Validation Errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789886/mysterious-eclipse-jsp-validation-errors)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone suggested to [add following dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6908115/517483) and it worked for me.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @nitind Yes, it is a maven project.