# cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'init-param'

Tags: servlets, xsd, web.xml, init-parameters

This is my `web.xml` xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
```

Here is servlet node

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <init-param> <!-- here is a problem -->
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

On the marked line xml validator says

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'init-param'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":enabled, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":async-supported, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":run-as, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":security-role-ref, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":multipart-config}' is expected.

What is wrong and how do I correct this error?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

The order of elements in `web.xml` matters and in all examples I've come across, the `<load-on-startup>` comes after `<init-param>`.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: You would think that there is a NICE way of saying that! instead of Invalid content was found starting with element 'init-param'. Maybe a case of RTFM...then id be busy reading till the cows come home...

Comment: This is madness. It also needs to come _before_ `<async-supported>`

Comment: @CraigOtis just changed `<async-supported>` place to _after_ `<init-param>` and saved. After that changed back to its old place and saved. Problem is gone now. Eclipse is the best IDE ever :) **eclipse 2019-03**

Answer (score 17):

It's pedantic, but `<init-param>` has to come before `<load-on-startup>`, so:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param><!--here is a problem-->
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Configure according to this**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

      <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher-servlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value></param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher-servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>
```