# Java variable across multiple include blocks - variable cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, variables, include

I have jsp page that looks something like this:

## MyPage.jsp

```
<%@ include file = "/Title.jsp" %>
<%@ include file = "/Header.jsp" %>
<html>...</html>
```

In Title.jsp there is a instance of "user", let's say:

```
User user = new User();
```

in Header.jsp user is referenced as

```
user.setName("John");
```

Eclipse is showing error that "user cannot be resolved to variable" in header.jsp file. I perfectly understand why. **Is there a way to tell Eclipse to ignore this particular error for this particular variable?** Is there anything that can be done here?.

At work, I am supporting some old (and big and ugly) Java application that is actually a web application. I am trying to convert this Java Project to Java Dynamic Web Project. Before I converted it, somehow Eclipse didn't care about these hanging variables that are all over the place. Now, in Dynamic Web Project, Eclipse is complaining.

Rewriting the code is out of question. Each jsp file is consisted of multiple includes with tons of global variables. I don't won't to touch it more than I need to.

Comment: I don't think you can filter validations by variable name, you can do that by file type or folder. You can obviously get rid of all validations for JSP files, but I guess it does not interest you. BTW I can imagine Emacs users reading your question with satisfaction, surely there would be the way to do that in Emacs (I am not sure, since I use... Eclipse or Intellij)

Comment: I found similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268153/somevariable-cannot-be-resolved-error-indicated-in-eclipse-for-an-included-jsp which basically says the same, to turn validation off...

Comment: Yes, Eclipse is pretty hopless when it comes to JSP handling.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### Best Practices

Ideally, one shouldn't have any `<% // scriptlet %>` blocks in JSPs any more.

JSPs have evolved so much from simply hiding Java code behind Standard Actions and Custom Tags to using Expression Language, JSTL and now OGNL expressions to fetch the results (for the request just processed) from pre-populated JavaBeans available in any one of the application scopes (like session, request, page etc.) or sophisticated data stores (like ValueStack in Struts 2).

So, a proper solution would look something like *(can't use EL because we need a "user" reference)*

```
 <jsp:useBean id="user" class="foo.User" /> <!-- scope="page" by default -->
```

This line of code when added to `Title.jsp` would create a new `User` bean and add it to the `page` scope and this same line of code in `Header.jsp` would then retrieve the `User` bean from the `page` scope and give it a reference named `user` that can then be used throughout the rest of the file.

But, since the rest of the Java code isn't written with tags this won't make much sense. So, you could also simply pass the bean between the two JSPs as a request attribute using one of your <% // scriptlet %> blocks.

```
<% // in Title.jsp
  request.setAttribute ("user", new User());
%>

<% // in Header.jsp
  User user = request.getAttribute ("user");
  user.setName ("John Doe");
%>
```

### Answer

If the code base is too huge to salvage and using any of the best practices is just plain impractical; you could configure your Eclipse IDE to ignore JSP syntax validation errors or better only turn them off for JSP fragments or specific files and folders.

With your web project selected in the workspace go to `Project > Properties > Validation > JSP Syntax`. Then `Enable project specific settings` and turn off `Validate JSP fragments` as shown below.

[image: JSP validation off for fragments]

A JSP fragment is a `.jspf` file that contains a JSP/HTML segment without opening and closing header tags (unless it's a header or a footer fragment of course). So, although you would have to rename your files to `.jspf` for Eclipse to recognize them as fragments (and not validate); the main advantages are:

- files can be anywhere in your folder structure
- the extension clearly indicates it's an include
- new fragments will get identified automatically

If the number of include files is huge or they can't be renamed for some reason your next best option would be to move them into a separate folder (like `includes`) and then exclude the folder itself from JSP syntax validation.

Again, go to Project > Properties > Validation and with project specific settings enabled click on the browse type `[...]` button for accessing the `JSP Syntax Validator` settings.

[image: Validation settings]

In here, first create an `Exclude Group` and then `Add Rule` to ***exclude a folder*** (like *WebContent/includes* in the image) from JSP syntax validation.

[image: Exclude folder]

Now Eclipse would stop reporting errors for any JSP file dropped in this *includes* folder. You could ***use the same approach for individual files*** as well but how practical it is would again depend on how many such fragments you have.

*References:*
[How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202)

Comment: With eclipse neon, this option appears to be gone. Or has it moved somewhere else?

Answer (score 5):

To your question: Is there a way to tell Eclipse to ignore this particular error for this particular variable?  As noted above, the error is coming from the validation framework in Eclipse.  The best you can do is to tell eclipse to ignore that file - not that error or that variable.  To do so, right click on the project and pull up it's properties dialog.  Once there, select "Validation" and click the checkbox for "Enable project specific settings".  From there you can turn on or off specific validations.  Personally, I don't find the Eclipse validators all that useful and they take quite a bit of processing time, so I turn almost all of them off!   However, you have some fine grain control via the "Settings" column.  You hit the elipsis next to JSP Content Validator (for example) and you can specifically exclude only Header.jsp from there.

Hope this helps, it only provides the details to the earlier comments though.