# Include JSP with Java dependency on variable

Tags: java, jsp, include

I have a main JSP what is including another JSP with code like:

```
<div class="titulo" data-role="header" data-theme="a">
   <h1><span class="header-title"><span><%=titleHeader%></span></span></h1>
</div>
```

Like you can see, titleHeader is a variable what I have declared on my main JSP (because it depends of each main JSP) and I am doing a include of another JSP where I am using it.

Eclipse shows up an error. How can I face this problem?

Thank you.

I have found the answer: [Java variable across multiple include blocks - variable cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16593952/java-variable-across-multiple-include-blocks-variable-cannot-be-resolved)

Comment: Don't use scriptlets? How is `titleHeader` declared in the main JSP?

Comment: I have found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16593952/java-variable-across-multiple-include-blocks-variable-cannot-be-resolved

Answer (score 0):

Try with

`<c:out value="${titleHeader}" />`

Answer (score 0):

```
<% String titleHeader= "Some title " ;  %>
```

use your code

```
<div class="titulo" data-role="header" data-theme="a">
 <h1><span class="header-title"><span><%=titleHeader%></span></span></h1>
</div>
```

it will work